# Problem with log files whose names contain spaces

Tags: stata

In Stata to create a log file

1. Click: File → Log → Begin.
2. Command: `log using "working directory.log"`
3. When finished, type `log close`, to close the log file.

So, I have done 1. where I ended up saving it, but when I type 'working directory.log' in the command, it says error.

What am I doing wrong? I've tried brackets, square brackets, quotation marks etc. and still the same thing. Am I meant to save the file as `working directory.log`?

Comment: Opening a log file creates it and `log close` stops writing to it. You don't give any command exactly that "doesn't work", but if your command name includes a space then double quotation marks are essential in referring to it, e.g. `type "working command.log"`.

Comment: Yeah I think I had to type: 'log using "working directory. log"' as it said command: log using "working directory.log" and it said 'log file is already open' as a result.